# 3rd display: laptop and 2 displays

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors

Now my desktop extended to 2 monitors: laptop and display connected to laptop via hmdi.

I decided to add the 3rd monitor and connected it via d-sub to laptop.

Windows 7 detectes it in `Control Panel\Appearance and Personalization\Display\Screen Resolution`.

I select the 3rd monitor and choose `Extend desktop to this dislplay`. Click `Apply`, `Save Changes`. But `Multiple displays` field revert itselft to `Disconnect this display`. And there is nothing on the 3rd monitor.

My laptop video card is `Intel(R) HD Graphics 4000`. 3rd monitor model `BenQ FP71G+`.
Lapton model name is `samsung NP300E5X-A07RU`
Operating system: `windows 7 ultimate x64`

Seemingly [it's possible with my video card](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jOHBkFOyckY), but question is how to do it?

Comment: http://www.intel.com/support/graphics/intelhdgraphics4000_2500/sb/CS-033714.htm has info on Intel triple monitor support. Could you please add your system data (laptop model, operating system) to the question?

Comment: what happened when you connect the 2nd monitor via d-sub?

Comment: @MartheenCahyaPaulo when I connect the 2nd monitor via d-sub I hear windows sound `pabam`, and old 2 monitors turn to black and then return representation. And on the new monitor nothing changed.

Comment: Hm, so it's not a problem in the d-sub itself. I presume Marcus got it then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get a UGA external video card, it turns your USB 2.0/3.0 port to hdmi or dvi or vga port which u can use to connect your 3rd monitor. You will need to install drivers come with the uga card. It's a cheap solution to multiple monitors. You can connect up to 6 monitors with UGA cards. Each UGA card only cost $50.

My setup: one monitor connected to VGA port on my laptop,2nd monitor connected to hdmi port on my laptop,(my laptop has both VGA and hdmi port), the 3rd monitor connected to USB through a external UGA card)

Answer (score 3):

According to the [HD Graphics 4000 triple monitor support page](http://www.intel.com/support/graphics/intelhdgraphics4000_2500/sb/CS-033714.htm),

> In most cases, three independent displays are supported in the
>   following configurations:
>
> - If two of the displays are DisplayPort monitors
> - If one of the displays is an Intel® Wireless Display (Intel® WiDi)
> - If the built-in display is an Embedded DisplayPort (eDP)

Since you don't have any DisplayPort outputs on your machine, the setup you want only works if your internal monitor is connected via eDP, not LVDS.

> To check if your computer's built-in display uses an embedded
>   DisplayPort (eDP) or LVDS connector type: From the Windows desktop,
>   press Ctrl+Alt+F12 key combination. If prompted select Advanced Mode
>   application mode. Select Options and Support, change System
>   Information to Built-in Display. Check the Connector Type field.

If it turns out to be LVDS, this setup is unfortunately not compatible with your hardware.

Note that, as far as I know, the vast majority of current laptops don't use eDP as it's a new standard (except some 3D laptops), so it generally isn't possible to run 3 monitors off an HD 4000 GPU unless your laptop has DisplayPort. (Or if you run one monitor off WiDi.)

Comment: Ok, I pressed `Ctrl+Alt+F12`, then `Advanced Mode`, then [Options and Support](http://clip2net.com/s/2NQzb). When I Enable `Built-in Display` using hotkey in the table, my d-sub monitor turn on, but hdmi monitor turn off. When `Enable Digital Display` back my hdmi monitor turns on, but d-sub monitor turns off. Both variants give me only 2 desktops, not 3.

Comment: The tl;dr of my answer is that it **probably isn't possible to do 3 simultaneous monitors from your laptop**, sorry.

Comment: I might temper this with "the vast majority of *cheap* current laptops".  A noticeable number (probably still not a majority) of the higher end business-class stuff has moved to eDP with the current gen.

Comment: Oh, really? Interesting. Where does one find this sort of info on laptops? Manufacturer websites never seem to have detailed info like that.

Comment: Good luck finding that info outside of a detailed teardown style hardware review. :(

Answer (score 1):

To find out if your Intel laptop monitor is eDP or LVDS, hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>, select "options and support", "Information center" in the upper middle of the screen will be a drop down tab that should say "System Information". Then, next to it is a save button.  Select the "Sustem Information" drop down tab then select "Built-in Display"  Under general information will show the connector type.  Mine unfortunately is LVDS (and I don't have a "cheap" laptop).